# Search all ocurrences of string in array

Tags: c++, algorithm, string-matching

Let's say I have a string array **A** of size **n**, and **A** is *lexicographically sorted*, for example:

```
0: abcaoeir
1: acda
2: acdttt
3: acdy
4: degaeiour
5: utsss
```

given a string **S** of size **m**, how can I find the first index **i** and the last index **j** of **A** such that:

- **S** is prefix of **A[ i ]** and no **k < i** will have **S** as prefix of **A[ k ]**
- **S** is prefix of **A[ j ]** and no **k > i** will have **S** as prefix of **A[ k ]**

That is, **i** is the first index where **S** is prefix, and **j** is the last.

For example, given **A** and **S = "acd"** :

```
0: abcaoeir
1: acda         [this will be the i]
2: acdttt
3: acdy         [this will be the j]
4: degaeiour
5: utsss
```

How can I find such **i** and **j** in **O(m + lg(n))** time?

Comment: I see just downvotes but no downvoter say a thing...

Comment: Its a case of LCP Array.

Comment: how do I use LCP array for it? It gives me just the size of the prefix

Comment: You can use LCP Array in LCP-LR: [LCP array usage in finding the number of occurrences of a pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array)

Answer (score -1):

As the array is sorted, you could use `std::lower_bound`to find the start of the sequence (that's your lg(n)), then search forward linearly to find the end of the sequence (that's your m).

Comment: This answer is wrong. std::lower_bound will take time close to m*lg(n) because it can compare near to all m chars lg(n) times in worst case, and the linear search will take n in the worst case (and not m), so this solution is O(m(lg(n) + n)) = O(m.lg(n) + mn)

Comment: You seem to be including char-by-char comparison on the strings themselves in your complexity time. If that's the case then basically, you have no chance with the data structured in this way. Perhaps if you restructured your data into a trie?

Comment: this is possible, you just have to do binary search in the array using LCP-LR array not to repeat comparisons